# Limiting distribution of MLE for uniform distribution

Tags: statistics, uniform-distribution, probability-limit-theorems, maximum-likelihood

We consider iid random variables $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n\sim\mathcal{U}_{[0,\theta]}$ and are interested in the asymptotic behaviour of the corresponding MLE for $\theta$, i.e.
$$M_n:=\mathrm{max}_{i\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}}X_i.$$
More precisely, I would like to confirm explicitly that $M_n$ converges (in some sense) to a reversed-Weibull-distributed rv in distribution and I suppose that I am just missing some computational detail/trick/idea...

I thought I should try studying a standardised version of $M_n$ since that's what seems to be done in extreme value theory and more generally when studying limiting distributions.

We know that
$$\mathbb{E}_{\theta}[M_n]=\frac{n}{n+1}\theta,~~\mathbb{Var}_\theta[M_n]=\frac{n}{(n+1)^2(n+2)}\theta^2,$$
so I consider the cdf of
$$Z_n=\frac{M_n-\mathbb{E}_\theta[M_n]}{\sqrt{\mathbb{Var}_\theta[M_n]}}~~\mathrm{or}~~Z_n'=\frac{M_n-\theta}{\sqrt{\mathbb{Var}_\theta[M_n]}},$$
which leads to
$$\mathbb{P}_\theta(Z_n'\leq x)=\left(1+\frac{\sqrt{n}}{(n+1)\sqrt{n+2}}x\right)^n$$
and
$$\mathbb{P}_\theta(Z_n\leq x)=\left(1-\frac{1}{n+1}\left(1-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+2}}x\right)\right)^n$$
for $x\leq 0$ and $x\leq \theta/(n+1)$ respectively.
However, I don't see how the limit with respect to $n$ takes the form
$$\exp\left(-\left(\frac{1}{1+\xi x}\right)^{1/\xi}\right)$$
for some $\xi<0$ here. (I know that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}(1+x/n)^n=\exp(x)$)

How can I resolve this? Is it maybe just a clever alternative for the denominator $\sqrt{\mathbb{Var}_\theta[M_n]}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2950994/evaluating-lim-n-to-infty-frac1-theta-1-fracz-thetann-1

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Consider $T_n=n(\theta-M_n)$. From the distribution function of $M_n$, find the distribution function of $T_n$. Take the limit of the DF of $T_n$ as $n\to\infty$. Just  remember that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1+\frac{a}{n}\right)^n=e^a$. You would be easily able to identify the asymptotic distribution of $M_n$.

A quick search shows that this question has been answered in detail [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/130447/119261) on CV.

Comment: Alright, if I use your suggestion just without sign-changing and consider $\frac{n}{\theta}(M_n-\theta)$, this is actually close to $\frac{M_n-E[M_n]}{Var[M_n]}$, and as the limiting distribution of this, I get a flipped exponential distribution, right?
This is quite nice already!
However, firstly I wonder if you can easily argue that the limiting distribution would be the same if you take the exact values for expectation and variance; secondly, the question remains if we can somehow identify a reverse Weibull distribution here?!

Comment: @Mau314 The limiting distribution of $T_n$ would be an exponential distribution with mean $\theta$. This itself is the asymptotic distribution of $M_n$.

Comment: Yes, right. I just rewrote this so that it matches my framework from above a little better. Sorry, the two questions remain...

Comment: @Mau314 I would like to see the pdf of the reversed weibull variable you are talking about. If you treat the distribution of $T_n$ to be equal to the exponential distribution and transform to find the (limiting) distribution in terms of $M_n$ only, then you would be able to answer the last question. This is what you are asking I suppose.

Comment: @Mau314 I think what you were referring to regarding taking the 'exact values for expectation and variance' was the classical CLT. But I don't think it is applicable here; notably the limiting distribution of $\max(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ is not asymptotically normal.

Comment: Well, I can't tell you more about the Weibull-distribution than I wrote in the original question - it's cdf is supposed to be of the given form. But actually I'm already happy with the exponential distribution.
About the CLT, yes, of course. I just mean that $n/\theta(M_n-\theta)$ is not equal to $(M_n-\mu_n)/\sigma_n$, but they are "asymptotically equivalent" in the sense that subtrahend and factor are asymptotically equal, so I was wondering if we can easily deduce that $(M_n-\mu)/\sigma_n$ also converges to the exponential distribution.