# Evaluating $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\theta} (1-\frac{z/\theta}{n})^{n-1}$

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics

I am working on the following problem.

Let $X_1, X_2, ... ,X_n$ be iid Uniform$(0,\theta)$.  Show that if $Z_n=n(\theta-X_{(n)})$, $Z_n$ converges in distribution to exponential with mean $\theta$.

My work so far is that through transformation $f(z)=\frac{1}{\theta} \left(1-\frac{z/\theta}{n}\right)^{n-1} $

so 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\theta} \left(1-\frac{z/\theta}{n}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-z/\theta}$$

therefore it is true.

I have some iffy parts that I would like to confirm.

1), My understanding is that the cumulative density function has to approach to the converging function, i.e. 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} F_n(x) = F(x)$$
by definition, so I am not sure if what I did really works or not.

If not, I will try to derive the cdf for $f(z)$ and try from there.

2), I remember that 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n = e^x$$ but what if the exponent was $n-1$ instead?  Intuitively I think that it should go to the same limit, but how can I show work appropriately?

Comment: If $n\to\infty$ then $(1+\frac{x}n)^{n-1}=(1+\frac{x}n)^n)/(1+\frac{x}n)\to e^x$ because the numerator approaches $e^x$ and the denominator approaches $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go for CDF's at once (BTW it stands for "cumulative *distribution* function")

First of all let us do it for iid $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ that have *standard* uniform distribution (i.e. $\theta=1$ in this context). This to avoid the in my view annoying parameters.

Then for $x>0$ and $n$ large enough:
$$F_n(x)=P\left(n\left(1-Y_{(n)}\right)\leq x\right)=1-P\left(Y_{(n)}<1-\frac{x}{n}\right)=1-\left(1-\frac{x}n\right)^n$$

This reveals that $\lim_{n\to\infty}F_n(x)=F(x)$ for every $x\in\mathbb R$ where $F$ denotes the CDF of standard exponential distribution.

This justifies the statement $$n\left(1-Y_{(n)}\right)\stackrel{d}{\to}Z$$where $Z$ has standard exponential distribution.

Now take $X_i:=\theta Y_i$ for $i=1,2,\dots$ and it follows immediately that $$n\left(\theta-X_{(n)}\right)\stackrel{d}{\to}\theta Z$$

Here $\theta Z$ has exponential distribution with mean $\theta$.

Comment: That was quite swift.  I am assuming that it did not even need the transformation of the pdf, huh?

Comment: That indeed was not necessary. Next to that: CDF's always exist and there is only one of them for every distribution (nice properties). That cannot be said of PDF's. So if you can do it with CDF then take that route.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\theta} \left(1-\frac{z/\theta}{n}\right)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{\theta}\lim_{n\to \infty}[\frac{\left(1-\frac{z/\theta}{n}\right)^{n}}{\left(1-\frac{z/\theta}{n}\right)}]=\frac{1}{\theta}\cdot\frac{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{z/\theta}{n}\right)^{n}}{\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1-\frac{z/\theta}{n}\right)}=\frac{1}{\theta}\cdot\frac{e^{-z/\theta}}{1}=\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-z/\theta}$$

$$Q.E.D.$$